# How create a file in S3 without copy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want create a file in AWS S3, I dont want do a copy, I want create a file in S3, this is possible? I search on internet and not found the answer. I want do this use Docker Criu

Comment: How are you generating the file's content? What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

S3 objects are created via the [put-object](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html) function.

The `cp` command is only used through the `s3` CLI suite of commands which offer a simple abstraction above the true S3 API verbs.